# Can't add column breaks in sheets using JExcel API (JXL)

Tags: java, jxl

I am creating some code to copy and edit Excel sheets using the JExcel API plugin.

Unfortunately, when copying the template sheet, the column page breaks from the original sheet are lost.

The API has a "addRowPageBreak" function for the WritableSheet object, but no corresponding "addColumnPageBreak" version.

Does someone know of a hack to be able to add a column page break?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research, it seems that adding column page breaks is not possible in JXL. POI does allow this functionnality. Here is some sample code:

```
/**
 * Adds page breaks (columns and rows) to a sheet
 *
 * @param pageBreaks
 *            list of page breaks objects that contain the name of the sheet, as well as the column and row page breaks
 */
public static void addPageBreaks(ArrayList<PageBreak> pageBreaks)
{
    try
    {
        // Iterate for each page break object
        for (int i = 0; i < pageBreaks.size(); i++)
        {
            // Get sheet from page break object
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(pageBreaks.get(i).getSheetName());

            // Line needed to set the page breaks in the page
            sheet.setAutobreaks(false);

            // Iterate over all the row page breaks
            if (pageBreaks.get(i).getRowPageBreaks() != null)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < pageBreaks.get(i).getRowPageBreaks().size(); j ++)
                {
                    sheet.setRowBreak(pageBreaks.get(i).getRowPageBreaks().get(j));
                }
            }

            // Iterate over all the column page breaks
            if (pageBreaks.get(i).getColumnPageBreaks() != null)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < pageBreaks.get(i).getColumnPageBreaks().size(); j ++)
                {
                    sheet.setColumnBreak(pageBreaks.get(i).getColumnPageBreaks().get(j));
                }
            }
        }

        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFile);

        workbook.write(fileOut);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class PageBreak
{
private String sheetName;
private ArrayList<Integer> columnPageBreaks;
private ArrayList<Integer> rowPageBreaks;

/**
  * Constructor.
  *
  * @param sheetName
  *            name of the sheet to add page breaks to
  * @param rowPageBreaks
  *            list of rows which to add page breaks to
  * @param columnPageBreaks
  *            list of columns which to add page breaks to
  */
public PageBreak(String sheetName, ArrayList<Integer> rowPageBreaks, ArrayList<Integer> columnPageBreaks)
{
    this.sheetName = sheetName;
    this.rowPageBreaks = rowPageBreaks;
    this.columnPageBreaks = columnPageBreaks;
}

/**
  * Constructor.
  *
  * @param sheetName
  *            name of the sheet to add page breaks to
  */
public PageBreak(String sheetName)
{
    this.sheetName = sheetName;
    rowPageBreaks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    columnPageBreaks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

/**
  * Adds a column page break to the list of column page breaks
  *
  * @param columnPageBreak
  *            number of the column which to set as a page break
  */
public void addColumnPageBreak(int columnPageBreak)
{
    columnPageBreaks.add(columnPageBreak);
}

/**
  * Adds a row page break to the list of row page breaks
  *
  * @param rownPageBreak
  *            number of the row which to set as a page break
  */
public void addRowPageBreak(int rowPageBreak)
{
    rowPageBreaks.add(rowPageBreak);
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getColumnPageBreaks()
{
    return columnPageBreaks;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getRowPageBreaks()
{
    return rowPageBreaks;
}

public String getSheetName()
{
    return sheetName;
}

public void setColumnPageBreaks(ArrayList<Integer> columnPageBreaks)
{
    this.columnPageBreaks = columnPageBreaks;
}

public void setRowPageBreaks(ArrayList<Integer> rowPageBreaks)
{
    this.rowPageBreaks = rowPageBreaks;
}

public void setSheetName(String sheetName)
{
    this.sheetName = sheetName;
}
```

}